# Cannot view video from publisher using Chrome to iPad with OpenTok

Tags: webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I'm currently trying to set up a connection between my web client and my iOS app, but for some reason my iOS client only sees a black box when using Chrome (version 33). I can see the video just fine if I use Firefox (both in my app and when I put the browsers side-by-side, they can see each other).

This doesn't appear to be a documented [known issue](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/js/release-notes.html#knownIssues) with the JavaScript SDK, and I can't see any recent discussion about this on the forums (last post was mine).

The iOS sample can be located [here](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-webrtc) (`samples/OpenTokHelloWorld`) with the browser page in `samples/OpenTokHelloWorld/browser_demo.html`

I suggest `cd`'ing into samples/OpenTokHelloWorld and running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, as it can't be run from a `file:///` path.

Here is what my iPad sees:

Chrome:

[image: iPad view with Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: iPad view with Firefox]

And Chrome/Firefox (respectively), both publishing video from the same camera

[image: Chrome/Firefox]

**Edit**: after testing on other machines, it may be something specific to my environment even though none of my extensions run in Incognito and I don't have any custom plugins installed.

Comment: i'm not sure this is really stackoverflow content

Comment: @Coffee the OpenTok forums aren't any help. Even though this is pretty specific, could you elaborate as to why you don't think this is SO content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the OpenTok mobile SDKs with the specific webcam I was using has issues. On Android the video stream will display for a brief moment then segfault, and on iOS there will be no video at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this many times and could not reproduce what you are seeing in your chrome. 
Without seeing any console errors or iOS logs the best suggestion is to try clearing your cache, or maybe restarting your computer (longshot)

[image]

Comment: A coworker suggested trying a different webcam when we got it to work on two different computers, so I did on the machine which wasn't working and the different webcam appears to work. I tested the "bad" webcam on another machine, and confirmed it wasn't working there either. I see you work for TokBox -- is there a supported devices list?

Comment: In terms of webcams, TokBox does not have a list of supported webcams. We generally assume that all webcams should work. For Android, during beta period the only device that is guaranteed to work is Galaxy S3.

Comment: I see. I'll have to contact support then as it looks like a problem in the mobile SDKs. On Android it segfaults after displaying the video for a second, and on iOS it doesn't display the video at all.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You can email OpenTok support at support@tokbox.com